# Efficient way to convert Latitude/Longitude to XY

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates

I have a working `script` that converts `Latitude` and `Longitude` coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. However, I have to perform this for specific points at each point in time (`row by row`).

I want to do something similar on a larger `df`. I'm not sure if a `loop` that iterates over each `row` is the most efficient way to do this? Below is the `script` that converts a single XY point.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

point1 = [-37.83028766, 144.9539561]

r = 6371000 #radians of earth meters

phi_0 = point1[1]
cos_phi_0 = math.cos(np.radians(phi_0))

def to_xy(point, r, cos_phi_0):
    lam = point[0]
    phi = point[1]
    return (r * np.radians(lam) * cos_phi_0, r * np.radians(phi))

point1_xy = to_xy(point1, r, cos_phi_0)
```

This works fine if I want to convert between single points. The issue is if I have a large data frame or list (`>100,000 rows`) of coordinates. Would a `loop` that `iterates` through each `row` be inefficient. Is there a better way to perform the same function?

Below is an example of a fractionally bigger `df`.

```
d = ({
    'Time' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],       
    'Lat' : [37.8300,37.8200,37.8200,37.8100,37.8000,37.8000,37.7900,37.7900,37.7800],       
    'Long' : [144.8500,144.8400,144.8600,144.8700,144.8800,144.8900,144.8800,144.8700,144.8500],                               
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Comment: For very, very large lists parallelization will be helpful, otherwise, the approach is most probably good enough.

Comment: You can pass in the points individually to avoid the list lookup..but that's just nitpicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do this if I were you. (Btw: the tuple casting part can be optimized.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

point1 = [-37.83028766, 144.9539561]

def to_xy(point):

    r = 6371000  #radians of earth meters
    lam,phi = point
    cos_phi_0 = np.cos(np.radians(phi))


    return (r * np.radians(lam) * cos_phi_0,
            r * np.radians(phi))

point1_xy = to_xy(point1)
print(point1_xy)

d = ({
    'Lat' : [37.8300,37.8200,37.8200,37.8100,37.8000,37.8000,37.7900,37.7900,37.7800],       
    'Long' : [144.8500,144.8400,144.8600,144.8700,144.8800,144.8900,144.8800,144.8700,144.8500],                               
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['to_xy'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
         tuple(x.values),
         axis=1).map(to_xy)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Prayson. If I had a different set of input data and point1 changed. Would you recommend calling the first Lat/Long row if the df instead?

Comment: The function expects (lat,long) tuple as your parameter, so yes, the first has to be lat/long row :)  You can always make the function flexible by sensing the boundry. e.g. for a give country, we expect latitudes between a and b and  long between c and d. so if it is the opposite, switch the around :)